# Query returns both documents instead of just one

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

```
var res = esclient.Search<MyClass>(q => q
                .Query(fq => fq
                    .Filtered(fqq => fqq
                        .Query(qq => qq.MatchAll())
                        .Filter(ff => ff
                            .Bool(b => b
                                .Must(m1 => m1.Term("macaddress", "mac"))
                                .Must(m2 => m2.Term("another_field", 123))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

As far as I can understand the `bool` and `must` together are the equivalent of the `AND` operator. I've got an index with two documents in it, only one matches the two constraints (`macaddress` and `another_field`) but Elasticsearch returns both.

this is the mapping:

```
{
   "reviewer-test-index": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
         "historyRecord": {
            "properties": {
               "groupName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "groupNo": {
                  "type": "integer"
               },
               "instrType": {
                  "type": "integer"
               },
               "instrumentAddress": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "insturmentName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "macAddr": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "uhhVersion": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         },         
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1434557536720",
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "0",
            "version": {
               "created": "1050299"
            },
            "uuid": "FfQADLGVQVOPV3913exKsw"
         }
      },
      "warmers": {}
   }
}
```

I also tried to make a JSON query but I get 0 hits:

```
GET _search
{
  "query" :{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match_all": { }
    },
   "filter": {
      "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {"term" : { "macAddr" : "000A8D810F5A" } },
                {"term" : { "insturmentName" : "Amin's furnace" } },
                {"term" : { "instrumentAddress" : "8D810F5A"}},
                {"term" : { "uhhVersion" :  "v2.5"}},
                {"term" : { "groupName" :  "Amin's Group"}},
                {"term" : { "groupNo" :  2}},
                {"term" : { "instrType" :  60}}
            ]
         }
    }
  }
  }
}

Response:

{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 4,
      "successful": 3,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

Comment: Then there is something fishy with your analyzer. Can you provide the mapping for that index and both documents in question?

Comment: in the mappings I've got analyze=true and store=false for all the fields

Comment: And can you share the actual documents values for those fields that you think it should match?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I updated the post with mapping and a query example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`term` filters don't analyze the text to be searched. Meaning, if you search for `000A8D810F5A`, this is exactly what is searching for (upper-case letters included).

But, your `macAddr` and `insturmentName` fields and others are just `string`s. Meaning, they use the `standard` analyzer which lowercases the terms. So, you are searching for `000A8D810F5A` but in the index you probably have `000a8d810f5a` (notice the lowercase letters).

So, you need to either have those fields `not_analyzed` or analyzed with the `keyword` analyzer or, if you want to keep them analyzed by default with `standard` analyzer, add a `.raw` multifield that should be `not_analyzed` or `keyword` analyzed and use that in your search. For example, `"term" : { "macAddr.raw" : "000A8D810F5A" }`.

Suggested mapping:

```
  "mappings": {
     "historyRecord": {
        "properties": {
           "groupName": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           },
           "groupNo": {
              "type": "integer"
           },
           "instrType": {
              "type": "integer"
           },
           "instrumentAddress": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           },
           "insturmentName": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           },
           "macAddr": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           },
           "uhhVersion": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Suggested query:

```
{
  "query" :{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match_all": { }
    },
   "filter": {
      "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {"term" : { "macAddr.raw" : "000A8D810F5A" } },
                {"term" : { "insturmentName.raw" : "Amin's furnace" } },
                {"term" : { "instrumentAddress.raw" : "8D810F5A"}},
                {"term" : { "uhhVersion.raw" :  "v2.5"}},
                {"term" : { "groupName.raw" :  "Amin's Group"}},
                {"term" : { "groupNo" :  2}},
                {"term" : { "instrType" :  60}}
            ]
         }
    }
  }
  }
}
```